# Why does the text change after I set the Caret position for JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, caret

I'm creating a program which uses a JTextArea, and when I try to change the caret position it goes from this:

```
hello
Hello there
-
|
```

Code:

```
public void executeCommand(String cmdName){
    Boolean cmdFound = false;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < cmdNames.size(); i++){
        if(cmdNames.get(i).toLowerCase().equals(cmdName.toLowerCase())){
            cmdFound = true;
            cmds.get(cmdName).actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, 0, null));
            Config.cmdln.println("-");
            Config.cmdln.setCaretPosition(Config.cmdln.getText().length()); //part that changes
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(!cmdFound){
        Terminal.cmdln.println("Command " + "\"" + cmdName + "\"" + " not found.");
    }
```

to this:

```
hello
Hello there

|-
```

Code:

```
public void executeCommand(String cmdName){
    Boolean cmdFound = false;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < cmdNames.size(); i++){
        if(cmdNames.get(i).toLowerCase().equals(cmdName.toLowerCase())){
            cmdFound = true;
            cmds.get(cmdName).actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, 0, null));
            Config.cmdln.println("-");
            Config.cmdln.setCaretPosition(Config.cmdln.getText().length() - 1); //part that changes
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(!cmdFound){
        Terminal.cmdln.println("Command " + "\"" + cmdName + "\"" + " not found.");
    }
```

This is the output I want:

```
hello
Hello there
-|
```

Note: the "|" represents the caret

Let me know if you need any more code.

Comment: From what I understand you want to put the caret at the end of the text... If that's the case, simply remove the `- 1` on the line that sets the carret position

Comment: I tried that, but then I get a space in between

Comment: Is there another way to change the caret position?

Comment: I am not sure of the following, but you could add ` + 1` since you are printing `-` the line before.

Comment: That fixed it thank you so much. Put it in an answer so I can accept an upvote it.

Comment: *Let me know if you need any more code.* - you should ALWAYS post an [mre] when asking a question so we can see the entire context of the problem.

Comment: @camickr ok thank you for letting me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply replace `Config.cmdln.getText().length() - 1` by `Config.cmdln.getText().length() + 1` (the `-` has changed to the `+`).

This is possible since you are adding a character with the `println()` line before.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change this:

```
Config.cmdln.println("-");  // puts a new line after the dash
```

to this:

```
Config.cmdln.print("-");    // doesn't put a new line after the dash
```

If you want the blank line at the end, you might be able to add the new line after setting the caret.